# Are there any open access space journal repositories?

Tags: reference-request

I'm playing around with some machine learning software I've written. It would be theoretically possible to code this to answer real word questions (like those asked on this site). Of course any answers are only as complete as the sources the answer is constructed from. Are there any plain text document repositories for the field of space exploration?

Comment: Most entries in the [NASA Technical Reports Server](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp) (NTRS) are available as PDFs.

Comment: And if the PDF is text, as opposed to scanned images, you can use something like [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) to get the text out of it.

Comment: If you're looking for space data you should check out the [Planetary Data System](https://pds.nasa.gov/).

Comment: Do flight journals and logs count https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/how-were-the-flight-journals-of-the-apollo-missions-originally-transcribed-recor

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  In the documents collection of each bundle you can find science articles.  It is up to the data provider to include these.

> 8A.2.2 Document Products The range of relevant documents will depend
>   on the type(s) of data and the scope of the associated collections and
>   bundle. In general, completeness of information is the goal. **For a
>   typical planetary spacecraft mission, documents could include:** •
>   Mission Plan • Instrument papers • Instrument user guides •
>   Calibration reports • **Science articles** • Archive content, format, and
>   organization, e.g. Software Interface Specifications (SISs) • Software
>   user manuals

Comment: What is a "bundle"?

Comment: And where is this text quoted from? I find it hard to tell what your answer means.